# creating an accessor [] to return the value of public properties?

Tags: dart

I have a class, that i wanted to get the properties of.  The issue is that I am trying to access it similar to that of a map, instead of dot-operation.

So, I wanted to do:

```
UserGroup ug = new UserGroup(); 
ug["id"]
```

My class I have is:

```
class UserGroup extends JsProxy{
  int id;
  bool inUse;
  String description;
}
```

and i wanted to implement a function similar to this:

```
operator [](String str){ 
  //return ____ ?? null;
}
```

but i cant seem to figure it out.

Comment: There are different ways. You can use reflection or the reflectable package to get a list of properties to call them by name, you can hardcode the `operator[]{}` with `switch(str) { cale 'id': return id ...`. Where do you plan to use this - client, server, ...?

Comment: While it is used in both, this priomarily would be used for client side implemenations.  I cant have all the props in a map, it i would just access the map accordingly.  I was thinking that reflection would be too computationally intense.

Comment: Example:  Right now, I was trying to do something similar to a maps version of:  brace accessing and a keys getter.  The issue though is that i dont know how to do that with the global variables of a Dart class.  I wouldve loved there to be some sort of:   this[key] accessor or something, but alas, no.

Comment: Reflection isn't computational intensive, the issue is the output size of dart2js. Treeshaking can't know anymore what code to keep and what to prune because it's unused if you access classes and members by name unknown at compile time. The reflectable package requires you to declare what should be kept for reflective access thus doesn't suffer the code size issue like plain mirrors does (mirrors can be configure using `@MirrorsUsed()` but that is quite error prone.

Comment: ahhh, so it seems like the reflectable package might be a solid approach since it doesnt affect the tree shake as mirrors does.

Comment: I wouldn't say "doesn't affect" but it should be small. And yes, I'd also suggest reflectable.

Comment: I was looking up: https://github.com/dart-lang/reflectable/tree/master/reflectable  But i was having some difficulty figuring out an implementation which would suit my needs.

Comment: I haven't used reflectable directly myself (only some tests a while ago) Maybe someone else posts an example.

Comment: sounds good.  ill check as well and see how reflectable will allow me to reflect the values of a given key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just used a switch:

```
operator[](String key){
  switch(key){
    case "id": return id;
    case "inUse": return inUse;
    case "description": return description
  }
}
```